# How to best do EXCEL VBA on a production server

Tags: excel, vba

"The Business" wrote a  sophisticated Excel VBA Macro that scans multiple complex and irregular (multiple logical tables per tab) spreadsheets and produces a summary XLS.  Management wants IT to "productionize it" and run it on a server.

I've seen example of using the Jet drive to read regular tables (1 per tab) in a spreadsheet, but the spreadsheets are irregular and this macro does more than read, it sets cell formulas, etc. Therefore, I guess we need full VBA.

How do you do this in production if you can't install Excel on a production server?

Comment: There's more to consider here than how to get the code onto a server. Who's responsible for supporting this thing when it breaks, or when changes are required ("The Business" isn't going to have unfettered access to this thing once it's "productionized", is it?)? What are the rules about when this server can be patched (reboots, taking it offline) and testing the patches before they're deployed to the production server? What is the restriction preventing you from installing Excel on a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library for interacting with Excel files like [Spreadsheet Gear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) for instance... I am sure there are plenty of others. You can then read the Excel files and then produce the summary XLS. You'd need to tie it all together using VB. You wouldn't need to install Excel on the production server though.

Comment: There is a free library I've been using called [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](http://nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml). Works well and is free.

Comment: I don't remember if I tried Spreadsheet Gear before buting EasyXls. But I would not recommend EasyXLS. I've only used their product in one program and they already made 3 patches for me do to issues.